# Does order matter in theta join

Tags: sql, join

I got 3 relations

- customer (customer_name, city)
- loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
- borrower (customer_name, loan_number)

Find customer name, city and their loan amounts.

First query:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, c.city, l.amount
FROM borrower b
JOIN loan l USING (loan_number)
JOIN customer c USING (customer_name)
```

Second query:

```
SELECT c.customer_name, c.city, l.amount
FROM customer c
JOIN borrower b USING (customer_name)
JOIN loan l USING (loan_number)
```

Will the two queries produce same result?

Comment: Order of `INNER JOIN`s does not matter. Even more: optimizer is free to reorder them any way it likes.

Answer (score 3):

In inner joins (as opposed to outer joins), the order of tables does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** No. The order *doesn't* matter for INNER JOIN (and hence for theta join).

**Long Answer:**
INNER JOIN (or simply JOIN) between two or more tables gives you the intersection of the tables. Think of tables as sets and intersection of the tables is the common area of the sets where there in an overlap of data. No  matter where you place the sets, what's common between Set A, Set B and Set C (table A, table B & table C), won't change. Hence, order of tables *doesn't* matter for INNER JOIN.

When you do LEFT OUTER JOIN between two tables (two sets), you are not just taking the intersection of the two sets. You are actually taking the entire of the set (table) you placed on the left hand side. Similarly, for RIGHT OUTER JOIN, you are taking the entire of set (table) you placed on the right hand side. Hence, for LEFT and RIGHT OUTER JOIN, order of tables *does matter*.

For FULL OUTER JOIN, you are essentially taking not just the intersection, not just the table on the left or right, but the whole of two tables (or sets). Hence, order *doesn't* matter again for FULL OUTER JOIN.